# Heroku Django app static files not serving (error OSError: [Errno 2])

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles, static-files

I have developed an application in Python with Django, and I just deployed it on heroku servers.

My settings.py  file  has this content:

```
 PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
 STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'

 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
      os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static'),
 )


  STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
   )
```

when I run this command:

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

I get the following error:

```
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/nameOfApp/static'
```

the urls in templates to the files that were previously stored, such as CSS and javascript files which have this kind of url in the template files:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "javascripts/jquery.min.js" %}" ></script>
```

are served properly but the new files that are uploaded through admin panels are  not stored in the same place as the previous files in static folder, namely the new uploaded files should be stored in the the same folder as other static files such as CSS and javascripts,

Question:
so how should I modify the settings.py file so that it works properly?

Comment: uploaded files ? what about Media settings ?

Comment: @rajasimon MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL are left empty what shall I put them? btw they were also empty when I was running code locally but it used to work locally

Answer (score 2):

Media Root is for Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.

```
Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
```

Media URL is for handling the media file served from Media root.

Another important not is `you will need to configure these files to be served in both development and production`.

by adding this line in `urls.py` will do the tricks

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: my photos url in templates have src like this  src="/static/{{ image.image.url }}" and in models the model have attribute like this image = models.ImageField(upload_to= "images/subFolder") what should be the content of MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL to get them working?

Comment: MEDIA_URL = '/media/' and set this for MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media") –